# Es correcto decir "¿a verlo?"

Tags: gramática

Mi impresión es que es incorrecto, pero no veo claro el motivo. Como hablante nativo (España) me resulta natural "¿a ver?", mientras "¿a verlo?" me parece forzado. Sin embargo, si pienso en equivalentes, todos llevan el pronombre: ¿me lo enseñas? ¿me lo muestras? No entiendo por qué en un caso habría de ir sin pronombre y en otro(s) con.

Answer (score 4):

En [este sitio](https://www.espanolavanzado.com/gramatica-avanzada/380-a-infinitivo-imperativo#:%7E:text=A%20%2B%20infinitivo%20por%20imperativo&text=Se%20usa%20tanto%20para%20ordenar,%2D%C2%A1T%C3%BA%2C%20a%20callar!) podemos leer lo siguiente:

> El infinitivo puede usarse con valor de imperativo cuando va dirigido a una segunda persona del singular o del plural y aparece precedido de la preposición *a*; su uso es propio de la lengua oral coloquial.
>
> Se usa tanto para ordenar o solicitar a hacer actividades diversas...
>
> -*¡Tú, a callar!* — You, shut it!
>
> -*Niños, a dormir* — Kids, time for bed
>
> -*¡A trabajar! Esto no es un campamento de verano* — Get to work! This isn't a summer camp
>
> ...como en invitaciones vehementes a realizar alguna actividad, a menudo placentera:
>
> -*Todo el mundo, a comer* — Dig in, everyone
>
> -*A disfrutar, chicos* — Time to enjoy yourselves, guys
>
> -*A vivir que son dos días* — Live it up; life's short

El texto nada dice de que el verbo deba ser intransitivo, si bien todos los ejemplos son de verbos usados en forma intransitiva.

Como en general este uso del infinitivo es imperativo, es necesario que el verbo indique una acción **voluntaria**, y "ver", a diferencia de "mirar", es involuntario.

No obstante, usada no como orden sino como pedido, "a verlo/a/s" (entre signos de interrogación, no de exclamación) me resulta correcta:

(A) He traído una nueva mascota.
(B) ¿A ver**la**? (=¿Me permites verla?)

En imperativo, si bien no es usual pueden existir verbos transitivos con pronombres enclíticos:

- Ahora, ¡a aguantárse**la**!

En Argentina, se usa una expresión bastante grosera para indicar que hay que soportar un mal trago:

- ¡A comer**la**!

Lo más común, tratándose del imperativo, será que el objeto del imperativo no sea pronominal:

- ¡A lavar **los platos**!
- Todos, ¡a hacer **las camas**!
- ¡A hacer **la tarea**!
- Ahora, ¡a limpiar **el baño**!
- ¡A comer **toda la comida**!